# Is the set $T=\{A\in M(n,\mathbb R):\operatorname{trace}(A)=0\}$ connected?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $M(n,\mathbb R)$ be endowed with $\|.\|_2.$ Then *is* the set $T=\{A\in M(n,\mathbb R):\operatorname{trace}(A)=0\}$ connected? **My Attempt:**

**Yes:** $A=\{(a_{ij})_{n\times n}:a_{nn}=-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{kk}\}.$ Define $f:M(n,\mathbb R)\to M(n,\mathbb R):(a_{ij})\mapsto(b_{ij})$ where $$b_{ij}=\begin{cases}a_{ij}&if~(i,j)\ne(n,n)\\-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{kk}&if~(i,j)=(n,n)\end{cases}$$

Let for $p\in\mathbb N,$ $(a_{ij}^p)\to(a_{ij}).$ Then $\forall~i,j,~a_{ij}^p\to a_{ij}$ whence $-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{kk}^p\to -\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{kk}\implies b_{ij}^p\to b_{ij}\implies f(a_{ij}^p)\to f(a_{ij}).$ So $f$ is continuous on $M(n,\mathbb R).$

Obviously, $f(M(n,\mathbb R))\subset A.$ Again for $(a_{ij})\in A, (a_{ij})=f((b_{ij}))$ where $$b_{ij}=\begin{cases}a_{ij}&if~(i,j)\ne(n,n)\\0&if~(i,j)=(n,n)\end{cases}$$

So $f(M(n,\mathbb R))=A.$ Thus $A$ being a continuous image of a connected set is connected.

### **Is it correct?**

Comment: Yes, it looks fine. You could also argue that this set is path connected, actually convex, since it is a vector subspace, this would probably be a shorter argument.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Thanks so much.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Since determinant map is continuous I think I can conclude at once that the set of all orthogonal matrices and the set of all non-singular matrices are disconnected sets.

Comment: @SritiMallick Sure! You can conclude that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your proof looks fine to me. Here is a simpler proof:

For any $A \in T$ the set $\{ tA | t \in [0,1] \}$ is a path in $T$ between $0_n$ and $A$. Thus $T$ is path connected.

Answer (score 3):

As Olivier Begassat points out in the comments, the traceless $n\times n$ matrices form a vector subspace $T$ of the $n\times n$ matrices: for let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $v,w\in T$; then $tr(v+w) = tr(v)+tr(w)=0$, $tr(\lambda v) = \lambda tr(v) = 0$, and $tr(0) = 0\Rightarrow 0\in T$. Real vector spaces are connected, hence $T$ is connected.

Answer (score 2):

$A,B$ be trace $0$ matrices then just see  $tA+(1-t)B$ is also trace $0$ where $t\in [0,1]$

$\operatorname{trace}[tA+(1-t)B]=t\times \operatorname{trace}(A)+(1-t)\times \operatorname{trace}(B)=0$

so  the set is path connected.